# Is it possible to make buttons inside FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract work inside Fragments? FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

By running this code it will take me to `FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract` and it will appear 3 buttons: `Email`, `Google`, and `Facebook` button.

```
List <AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build());

ActivityResultLauncher <Intent> signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(), result -> {
    ...
});

signInLauncher.launch(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setAvailableProviders(providers).build());
```

[image]

I created `LoginFragment` and it contain 3 buttons, It looks similar like the image above but the difference is the 3 buttons inside `LoginFramgnt` are not inside the `FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract` activity.

**What I'm looking for?**

I'm looking for a way to make buttons inside `LoginFragment` do the same functionality that buttons inside the `FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract` activity does.

Comment: Just use the contract in your fragment then? That API works in both.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I'm new with FirebaseUI, If I put the code above inside LoginFragment it will take me to the FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract activity. I don't want it to go to that activity. Inside LoginFragment there are 3 buttons if I clicked on the Google button then I want to do the same functionality as the Google button inside FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract activity.